# Google Wifi + PiHole: Redirecting DNS requests

Tags: dns, pihole, google-wifi

Current setup involves 3 mesh google wifi devices + 1 Raspberry PI 1 B model running pihole. Most of the time it runs fines as it is, but I've noticed some devices (i.e. Chromebooks, chromecasts, etc) skip the dns configured in google wifi and go to directly to 8.8.8.8. I wonder how could I redirect these request to the PiHole. I'm suspecting I might need an additional piece of hardware.

Comment: Chromecasts and likely some other Google devices have their DNS servers hardcoded, so you cannot just reconfigure it. If you got a user-definable firewall (e.g. a pfsense/OPNsense box), you could explicitly block any DNS requests that try to bypass your DNS-forwarder (pihole); this could work.

Other idea would be bypassing by using static routes (configurable without a dedicated firewall).

Comment: indeed, yet I don't think I can add static routes to google wifi, pfsense sounds overkill at firsthand but I look into it.  Thanks